# Improving Polymorphism and Decorator pattern in Go

Tags: go, design-patterns

I'm working through a design patterns book and trying to apply the patterns to Go as a way to learn both.

Currently I have reached the decorator pattern and I ran into a scenario I was curious about.

Here is some sample code:

```
type Beverage interface {
    getDescription() string
    cost() float64
}

type HouseBlend struct{}

func (hb *HouseBlend) getDescription() string {
    return "House Blend Coffee"
}

func (hb *HouseBlend) cost() float64 {
    return .89
}

type Mocha struct {
    b Beverage
}

func (m *Mocha) getDescription() string {
    return m.b.getDescription() + ", Mocha"
}

func (m *Mocha) cost() float64 {
    return m.b.cost() + .20
}
```

**What is the difference between**

```
var hb Beverage = &HouseBlend{}

//This works since hb is an interface type
hb = &Mocha{
    b: hb,
}
```

**And**

```
hb := &HouseBlend{}

//This assignment fails since Mocha is not type HouseBlend
hb = &Mocha{
    b: hb,
}
```

This also works

```
hb := *new(Beverage)

    hb = &Espresso{}

    hb = &Mocha{
        b: hb,
    }
```

Is there a shorthand way of giving my variable **hb** the interface type or does it need to be explicit in order to be able to "decorate" my struct and reassign the variable to different types?

Any suggestions on improving the decorator pattern here and achieving clean polymorphism are  welcome. Thank you!

Comment: There is github repo with design patterns implemented in golang: https://github.com/AlexanderGrom/go-patterns

Comment: "I'm working through a design patterns book and trying to apply the patterns to Go as a way to learn both" You will learn how to write bad Go code. That's all. The typical OOP design patterns solve problems of traditional/(single)inheritance OOP languages. Some of those just do not exist in Go or have a totally different idiomatic solution. What you try to do will lead to frustration and teach you bad Go.

Comment: @Volker are there any specific projects written in Go that you would recommend taking a look at on GitHub?

Comment: The stdlib. It's not "beautiful" code but it contains a lot of sensible things in a Go'ish way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var hb Beverage` is how you explicitly give the variable a type. Implicit typing will always get the type of the value you put into it. I'm not sure what you're looking for in terms of "shorthand" here, as `var name Type` is already pretty short, but if you really want to use a short variable declaration you could use a type conversion:

```
hb := Beverage(&HouseBlend{})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the short form and declare `hb` as an interface using:

```
hb:=Beverage(&HouseBlend{})
```

This piece of code is not exactly correct:

```
// You allocate a pointer to an interface, and redirect it to get an uninitialized interface value
hb := *new(Beverage)

// Here, you throw away the value of the first assignment
hb = &Espresso{}
```